# Step through a word table selection with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been trying to write a Macro that changes some formatting in big tables in Word for me. I tried to find this information, but as soon as there are tables, the information is for excel.

So the situation I got is this, I got a table with 6 columns. The first two columns will get selected, the Macro started. Now I'd like it to read the first cell of the selection from the top left, then I do some manipulation/calculations with it, then I'd like to write back the manipulated data, move on to the cell to the right, read the data, manipulate it, write back something and then do so till the end of the Selection.

Can someone help me with a code skeleton? That would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible skeleton, it loops through columns 1 and 2 of a preexisting table.

```
Sub TestTable()

Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim docDocument As Word.Document
Dim tblTable As Word.Table
Dim c As Word.Cell
Dim sString As String
Dim iColumnNumber As Integer

Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set docDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open("<location of your document e.g. C:\MyDoc.doc>")
Set tblTable = docDocument.Tables(1)

For iColumnNumber = 1 To 2
    For Each c In tblTable.Columns(1).Cells
        sString = c.Range.Text
        'Do something
    Next c
Next iColumnNumber

'wordApp.Visible = True

Set tblTable = Nothing
Set docDocument = Nothing
Set wordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```